# Выровнять 2 элемента формы в одной строке bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap

Пытаюсь выровнять select и input в одной строке, но выходит криво. Как быть? Или нужно самому дописывать css?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
div#sample_div {
    width: 250px;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="sample_div">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group field-middle_name">
      <div class="col-sm-7 row">
        <select name="prefix_id" id="prefix_id" class="form-control" title="Префикс" required="required">
        <option value="">Префикс</option>
      </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 row">
        <input type="number" name="sample_number" id="sample_number" class="form-control" placeholder="Номер" title="Номер образца" required="required">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="help-block row"></div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Обратитесь в техподдержку bootstrap, они напишут вам css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <div id="sample_div">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group field-middle_name row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6 no-padding">
        <select name="prefix_id" id="prefix_id" class="form-control" title="Префикс" required="required">
        <option value="">Префикс</option>
      </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6 no-padding">
        <input type="number" name="sample_number" id="sample_number" class="form-control" placeholder="Номер" title="Номер образца" required="required">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="help-block row"></div>
  </form>
</div>


.no-padding{
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/LeaeQgb.png А чтобы они занимали всю ширину?

Comment: добавь класс no-padding дивам и в стилях - 
.no-padding{
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Всё работает.